# Difference between {1,2,3} and {1..3}

Tags: bash

Is there a difference between the sequences `{1,2,3}` and `{1..3}`?

For example if I have some files

```
file.1
file.2
file.3
```

and I want to `cat` them together is it safe to use `cat file.{1..3} > file`?

What I know is that `cat file.*>file` could cause problems because the shell can expand the files in a random way sometimes (I think this depends on the inodes, does it?)

Comment: use `cat file.[123] >file`

Comment: The order of expansion of `file.*` is not dependent on the inodes. It always sorts them lexicographically, which could depend on your locate setting.

Comment: "depends on the inodes" sounds like a phase from one of the better researched criminal-minds-eqsue "computer" scenes.

Comment: @AlecTeal it seems to be that I mixed this up with another situation I had once

Comment: @mikeserv, since that method isn't mentioned in any of the posted answers, would you mind adding it as an answer and explaining it?

Comment: @Wildcard - it isn't exactly relevant to the question, though...

Comment: @mikeserv, I believe I got it—it's a shell glob, so it only expands to files that actually exist, right?  Vs. `file.{1..3}` which expands to all three whether or not they exist.

Comment: @Wildcard - right, as long as at least one exists, that is. If not it expands not at all and `cat` errors with `file.[123] not found` or something very useful.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`{1..3}` and `{1,2,3}` produce the same result, but with different way.

In general, `{n1..n2}` (which came first from `zsh`, `bash` and `ksh` copied it later) where `n1` and `n2` are integers produce all numbers between `n1` and `n2`. While `{x,y,z}` produce three characters `x`, `y` and `z`.

In your case, you're safe to use `cat file.{1..3} > file`

Now, in case of `cat file.*>file`, you used the [shell globbing](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_06), which produce all file name start with `file.` and the result will be sorted base on the collation order in current locale.

You are still safe, but not anymore when you have more than 10 files. `{1..10}` will give you `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10`. While with globbing, you will get `1 10 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9`

Answer (score 8):

The difference is that one is a list and the other a sequence. `{1,2,3}` expands to three specific elements, `1`,`2`, and `3`. `{1..3}` expands to the list of numbers between one and three. In this particular case, they are the same and you can use either of the two. `file.*` will expand to all the files and directories in the current directory whose name starts with `file.`. If you only have `file.1`,`file.2` and `file.3` then that too is equivalent to the other two.

As for its causing problems, I don't see why. You might be thinking of

```
$ cat file.* > file.txt
cat: file.txt: input file is output file
```

That, however, is a completely different issue. The only other problem I can think of is that your shell might not list the files in the correct order. For example:

```
$ touch file1 file11 file2
$ echo file*
file1 file11 file2
```

To solve that, you can use `zsh` instead of `bash` (see [here](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers) for details):

```
% echo f*(n)
file1 file2 file11
```

In general, the three approaches are not the same. It depends on what you want to do. In those cases where the three return the same output then, yes, you can use any of them. It makes no difference. All of these expansions are done by the shell and happen *before* they are passed to whatever command uses them.

Comment: wouldn't there be a problem with `*` if I had more or equal 10 files, if I depend on the right order?

Comment: @syss no. It would be a problem if you had more than [`ARG_MAX`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/120842/22222) files but that will be way, way more than 10.

Comment: @terdon He was asking if they'll appear in numerical order (i.e. not "1, 10, 2"), not if they'll overflow the argument array.

Comment: @terdon I think @syss is right that the output of `cat *` is not well defined. The output depends on the shell and the environment. See [Sebastian's comment](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/153011/how-do-i-distribute-a-large-download-over-multiple-computers/153017#comment249945_153017).

Comment: Won't adding `.txt` solve the issue with `file.*`?

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel what issue with `file.*`?

Comment: `cat: file.txt: input file is output file`.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel oh, yes, of course that will fix it since the glob isn't matching the output file. The point was about those cases where the glob _does_ match the output file.

Comment: Gotta ask, how does cat know the input file is the output file? (because `> thing` is telling the shell "spew stdout over there")

Comment: @AlecTeal `cat` doesn't, this is all done by the shell. Shell commands are read right to left, so when you `cat file.* > file.txt`, `file.txt` is created first and then the `file.*` is expanded. So the shell complains about its input file being its output file.

Answer (score 6):

They are the same, but it depends on bash version you have installed if they are available.

From [this](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/special-chars.html#BRACEEXPREF) page:

> ```
> {xxx,yyy,zzz,...} probably in all bash versions
>
> {a..z} introduced in bash 3
>
> {<START>..<END>..<INCR>} new in bash 4
> ```